# My VBA code is not working while using the do while loop

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code below is not looping. Kindly help

```
Public Sub FunWithLoops()

' Create a loop using Do while loop.
'The aim is to go through a list of numbers down a row, highlight them with a different color if greater than 10.

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    
    Do While i <= 10
        If ActiveCell.Value > 10 Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        'interior changes the background color
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    
    i = i + 10
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please indent you code properly, to help people help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the value of `i` against the static value of 10. You then increment `i` by 10. So the loop executes once, always. You essentially don't have a loop and just some extraneous code as is.

I generally would use a `For` Loop do go down the rows, as its made for incrementing at set intervals.

```
Sub FunWithForLoops()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in Column A
        
        For i = 1 To lr
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value > 10 Then 'Test Column A, Row i
                .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed 'Modify Column A, Row i
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

You can do it with a `While` as well, you just need to increment yourself.

```
Sub FunWithWhileLoops()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
        i = 1
        Do While i <= lr
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value > 10 Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With      
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just correcting your code without making too many changes you might not be ready to go for:

```
Public Sub FunWithLoops()

' Create a loop using Do while loop.
'The aim is to go through a list of numbers down a row, highlight them with a different color if greater than 10.

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    
    Do While i <= 10
        If ActiveCell.Value > 10 Then ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select  
       i = i + 1 ' change this to + "1" not + "10"
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Please note that your `ActiveCell` must always be set BEFORE you run the routine, because there's nothing in the routine to set the `ActiveCell` first, like a line:

```
Range("A2").Select
```